# Is E0 countable?

Tags: general-topology

Given $E\subset\mathbb{R}$

let $E_0 = E - int(E)$

> Is $E_0$ countable?
>
> If yes, How can I show that $E_o$ is countable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't know.

For instance, let $E = \mathbb {Q}$. Then int$(E) = \emptyset$. Hence $E  - $int$ (E) = E$. And the rationals are countable.

But letting $E$ be the irrationals, we get the same result, except the irrationals are uncountable.